# Choosing a test framework for a JSF based webapp

Tags: java, testing, jsf

I am confused between the following test framework/tools:

1. JUnit
2. Shale
3. FitNesse

I need a test framework which is lean and generic in a way that the test cases can be re-used later by any other web application.

Any suggestions and other testing tool for the same ?

Answer (score 2):

[JSF Testing Tools](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/12/jsf-testing-tools) is not the latest article, but giving a nice overview.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what you want to test. If you want functional end to end test then which framework you use to build the webapp doesn't matter much and my preference is [Selinium 2/WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/). If your intention is to do white-box testing then I suggest [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit) or [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian).